# Can't find printer driver files in terminal after downloading

Tags: command-line, drivers, printing, canon

I don't have much experience with Terminal. I'm trying to install printer drivers for a Canon MX494.  I've downloaded (multiple copies lol) of the drivers (`.deb` and `.rpm`) and Terminal can't find them.  Where should I be putting them?  I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If you lack experience with the terminal, you can just double click the .deb file to install it.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find them in your `~/Downloads` directory. When you open a terminal you usually start in your user's home directory, so typing

```
ls
```

Will show you what's in there. If you see `Downloads` (or, if your locale is not English, some equivalent in your language) type

```
cd Downloads
```

Or if you don't see it

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then run `ls` again and hopefully there are your drivers. For Ubuntu you want `.deb` not `.rpm` packages. To install a `.deb` file (replace name-of-file with the name of the file!)

```
sudo dpkg -i name-of-file.deb
```